# data transfer from PL(fpga) to the PC via ethernet

Tags: vivado, zynq, vivado-hls

I work with Zedboard and vivado v2017.3. 
I have a custom IP in the PL part of zynq generating 32 bit values and stores them in one of the registers, say slv_reg0 (address : 0x43c00000). 
In the PS part I read this register and I can print it in the gtkterm (simple one).
I now want to transmit these values over ethernet to to the PC. 
Any suggestion on how to carry out this?

Thanks,
Upasana.

Answer (score 1):

Xilinx supplies sample programs, one of these is an echo server. It should be quite simple to change it so that it serves the data you generate instead of just echo-ing the received message, and you can learn out of it how to use the lwip library in case you want a more suitable solution.